# Unable to log in windows 7

Tags: windows, multi-boot

I have installed windows 7, ubuntu-14.04,ubuntu-13.04 I recently downgrade my OS from windows 10 to windows 7. So I had two windows log in options, one is for windows 7 and another one for windows 10. When I tried to log in windows 10, its loading windows 10 starting animation with windows 10 logo (but not allowing me to enter windows 10  because I downgraded that OS). I don't know how that new option created in boot menu even after downgrading OS.

I tried to delete the other OS except (windows 7) in my system using PC - EasyBCD, like [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=heO1n73Ua4Q)

In EasyBCD "BCD backup and repair" option in clicked "recreate \ repair boot files". Then I restarted system after that its loading windows 10  (loading logo) OS but not entering me into OS. Its not showing any other OS in boot menu.

I'm unable to use my laptop because of this, Please help me how to solve this without loosing windows 7 and data.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A very good way is to use the original Windows 7 installation CD/DVD.
You have to repair the Master Boot Record (MBR).
To fix the MBR use the command - bootrec /fixmbr

It is very well explained here:
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/32523/how-to-manually-repair-windows-7-boot-loader-problems/

Another good source can be found at the Microsoft support site:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/927392

After you repair the Windows boot, you can use EasyBCD to make dual-boot for Ubuntu.

Comment: Ty, I will try it. Will I lose any data?

Comment: No data is lost. The partition remains untacked, just the MBR is repaired in this operation. You can also execute afterwards the command:
bootrec /fixboot
This is an even more useful command, as it writes a new boot sector onto the system partition.

Comment: Sir, I tried that but I got the message "The volume does not contain a recognized file system." Please make sure that all required file system drivers are loaded and that the volume is not corrupted"

Comment: \scanos command gave "Total identified windows installations :0 "

Comment: Are you able to see the Volume if you boot from a HirenBootCD, for example, in the Mini XP menu?
I would try this first, to make sure the partition is OK, and is healthy.
Do not worry if you haven't made any partition changes the data is there.
I would also use AOMEI Partition Assistant (Free) to build a bootable CD or USB and try to see if the partitions look OK.
http://www.disk-partition.com/ - here is the Free Aomei Partition Assistant.

Comment: In my case I have Windows 10 on partition 1, HDD-D on Partition2, Linux SWAP on Partition3 and Ubuntu 15.04 on Partition4
Here are screenshots how I made it boot with EasyBCD:
http://vi8.info/pic/2015-09/EasyBCD-01-Overview.jpg
http://vi8.info/pic/2015-09/EasyBCD-02-Overview.jpg
http://vi8.info/pic/2015-09/EasyBCD-03-Linux-Entry.jpg